# Multiple group-by with one common variable with pandas?

Tags: pandas

I want to mark duplicate values within an ID group. For example

```
ID  A   B
i1  a1  b1
i1  a1  b2
i1  a2  b2
i2  a1  b2
```

should become

```
ID  A   An  B   Bn
i1  a1  2   b1  1
i1  a1  2   b2  2
i1  a2  1   b2  2
i2  a1  1   b2  1
```

Basically `An` and `Bn` count multiplicity within each `ID` group. How can I do this in pandas? I've found `groupBy`, but it was quite messy to put everything together. Also I tried individual groupby for `ID, A` and `ID, B`. Maybe there is a way to pre-group by `ID` first and then do all the other variables? (there are many variables and I have very man rows!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Also I tried individual groupby for ID, A and ID, B

I think this is a straight-forward way to tackle it; As you suggest, you can `groupby` each separately and then compute the size of the groups. And use `transform` so you can easily add the results to the original dataframe:

```
df['An'] = df.groupby(['ID','A'])['A'].transform(np.size)
df['Bn'] = df.groupby(['ID','B'])['B'].transform(np.size)
print df

   ID   A   B An Bn
0  i1  a1  b1  2  1
1  i1  a1  b2  2  2
2  i1  a2  b2  1  2
3  i2  a1  b2  1  1
```

Of course, with lots of columns you could do:

```
for col in ['A','B']:
    df[col + 'n'] = df.groupby(['ID',col])[col].transform(np.size)
```

The `duplicated` method can also be used to give you something similar, but it will mark observations within a group after the first as duplicates:

```
for col in ['A','B']:
    df[col + 'n'] = df.duplicated(['ID',col])
print df

   ID   A   B     An     Bn
0  i1  a1  b1  False  False
1  i1  a1  b2   True  False
2  i1  a2  b2  False   True
3  i2  a1  b2  False  False
```

**EDIT**: increasing performance for large data. I did it on a large dataset (4 million rows) and it was significantly faster if I avoided `transform` with something like the following (it is much less elegant):

```
for col in ['A','B']:
    x = df.groupby(['ID',col]).size()
    df.set_index(['ID',col],inplace=True)
    df[col + 'n'] = x
    df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks! `['A']` seemed confusing to me since technically `np.size` wouldn't need that :) Is there any possibility or performance gain from pre-grouping by `ID`? Since it's common to all groupBys and due to the large table it takes a bit long.

Comment: The ['A'] doesn't matter for `np.size`; it matters for `transform`. Transform will only know to return a single column if we send it a single column

Comment: I could be wrong, but I doubt it would help much; I'm guessing that `transform` is the bottleneck. For example, using `duplicated` might be faster (although, I know it isn't exactly what you want).

Comment: See me edit for a less elegant but, at least, faster for me with a larger dataset solution.

Comment: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6496 is the transform speed up - not implemented ATM (but easy enough to inline)